# How to update value in array in loop through

Tags: php, arrays

I try to update value in array using foreach loop. then print the array with updated value. I post my current code here. Kindly reply with sample code. thanking you.
here is my array:

```
[associated_branch] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [store_id] => 0
                            [store_name] => Bazar Kolkata
                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [location] => Sonarpur
                                )

                            [address_line1] => J L N Road
                            [address_line2] => Kolkata
                            [city] => 4
                            [state] => 24
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [store_id] => 16
                            [store_name] => KC DAS
                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [location] => Garia Hat
                                )

                            [address_line1] => kolkata
                            [address_line2] => 
                            [city] => 4
                            [state] => 24
                        )

                )
```

and i want:

```
[associated_branch] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [store_id] => 0
                            [store_name] => Bazar Kolkata
                            [location] => Sonarpur
                            [address_line1] => J L N Road
                            [address_line2] => Kolkata
                            [city] => 4
                            [state] => 24
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [store_id] => 16
                            [store_name] => KC DAS
                            [location] => Garia Hat
                            [address_line1] => kolkata
                            [address_line2] => 
                            [city] => 4
                            [state] => 24
                        )

                )
```

My Sql:

```
$assoBrSql="SELECT store_id, store_name, location, address_line1, address_line2, city, state FROM ".DB_MY_PREFIX."my_web_stores WHERE store_id IN($row[branch_ids]) AND cur_status=1 && is_more_branch =1 AND associated_branch IS NOT NULL";
                $branches = $db->ExecuteQuery($assoBrSql);
                $row['associated_branch']=$branches;

                foreach ($row['associated_branch'] as $key => $value) {

                    $locsql="SELECT location FROM " .DB_MY_PREFIX. "my_localities WHERE location_id='".$value['location']."'";
                    $locrows=$db->ExecuteQuery($locsql);
                    $row['associated_branch'][$key]['location']=$locrows[0];

                }
```

how to build this?

Comment: Why aren't you using joins in your query instead of issuing on extra query for each record in your initial result ?

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to change:

```
$row['associated_branch'][$key]['location']=$locrows[0];
```

to

```
$row['associated_branch'][$key]['location']=$locrows[0]['location'];
```

You're currently appending the result of the second query, which is an array containing a single element 'location'.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be more than one location for the branch, then you could change your initial query to use a subquery with groupconcat to get all of the locations. Something like this

```
$assoBrSql="SELECT store_id, store_name, location, address_line1, address_line2, city, state, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.location) as locations FROM " .DB_MY_PREFIX. "my_localities a WHERE a.location_id=location) as locations FROM ".DB_MY_PREFIX."my_web_stores WHERE store_id IN($row[branch_ids]) AND cur_status=1 && is_more_branch =1 AND associated_branch IS NOT NULL";
                $branches = $db->ExecuteQuery($assoBrSql);
                $row['associated_branch']=$branches;
```

Code not tested written in editor, hopefully no typos, etc. ;)